# How to close the parent dialog once the child dialog opens, using Material UI React

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui

Using Material UI React, On a button click, a dialog opens, on clicking yes on that dialog another dialog opens over the parent dialog. How can I close the parent dialog before opening the child dialog

Comment: If the child dialog/modal is rendered by the Parent dialog, then it will be removed as the parent component is removed / unMounted. One way is to render them both in the same level and use state higher up.

Comment: I want the parent dialog to close once the child dialog opens

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the dialogs in a wrapper component and have both point to the same reference for their `open` states.

Take a look at this sandbox for a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-star-cox1g

```
function Dialogs() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen("first")}>Open first dialog</Button>

      <Dialog open={open && open === "first"}>
        <DialogTitle>First Dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={() => setOpen("second")}>Close First Dialog</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>

      <Dialog open={open && open === "second"}>
        <DialogTitle>Second Dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={() => setOpen(null)}>Close Second Dialog</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}
```