# How to prevent flickering in child dialog opened from parent dialog - React + @Mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It's possible to avoid the flickering when open child dialog and close parent dialog?
An example is available in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/59302280/2267053

Comment: Use one dialog and change its content only

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.